# An ios application running in background

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile, background, call

While my application is running in background, i want to know if there is an incoming call and send an email like "phone is calling..."

is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. This is not possible.

It also isn't possible to send an email without user interaction unless you use an external server to do the sending of the email

Comment: ok, dont think send a mail.
while an app in background state, i want to run a code block like doSomeCalculation() when the incoming call interrupts is coming, is it possible? 

i just try to understand ios architecture

Comment: No once your app is in the background it is in a suspended mode. Only audio, location tracking and voip client are allowed to keep running in the background. All other apps that try to keep a process running will be killed by system. Try to use on of the background modes to get past the background running restriction is not allowed in the appstore.

Comment: Nothing other than location tracking, voip or background download of data is allowed or possible (unless you jailbreak).

Answer (score 0):

[CTCall](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCall/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CTCall) in CoreTelephony will let you monitor the state of incoming and outgoing calls.  It's true you cannot send an email without user interaction except via a direct connection with SMTP (and I wouldn't want to route them through *my* mail server!) Nick Bull is correct, I think, about the [restrictions on long-running background tasks.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW24)